# Keras Model Performance Changes

Tags: machine-learning, keras, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am on learning curve of neural network , using Keras to forecast next value based on previous specified window. Here is my code

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler,StandardScaler 
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator

scaler = StandardScaler() scaler.fit(train)
scaled_train = scaler.transform(train) 
scaled_test  = scaler.transform(test)


# define generator 
n_input = 47 
n_features = 1 
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_train, scaled_train, length = n_input, batch_size=12)
initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal()

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(12,activation = 'relu', input_shape = (n_input, n_features),kernel_initializer = initializer))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mae')
```

Problem is every time when I retrain model without making any changes , my model performance gets changed. Normally it should change based on any changes in parameter e.g. (new hidden layers or changes in activation function etc)

Comment: This is due to random weight initialization.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy How can I initialise same weights before every training? I used Xavier weight initialisation tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(), The Glorot normal initializer, also called Xavier normal initializer